# Relation between Jordan normal form and cyclic module decomposition

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, vector-spaces, modules, cyclic-decomposition

Let $V$ be a vector space over $\mathbb{C}$, we consider it as a $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module by choosing a linear map $\varphi:V\rightarrow V$ and for $f(x)\in\mathbb{C}[x]$ and $v\in V$, define:
$$ f\cdot v=f(\varphi(v))$$
Suppose we know that $V$ is written as direct sum of cyclic modules as follows:
$$V=\mathbb{C}[x]/\langle g_1(x)\rangle\oplus \cdots\oplus \mathbb{C}[x]/\langle g_r(x)\rangle \tag{$*$}$$
where $g_i(x)$'s are the annihilators of the cyclic modules.

My question is:
Do $g_1(x)\cdots g_r(x)$ tell us anything about the Jordan blocks of the map $\varphi$? What about the minimal and characteristic polynomials? 
Furthermore, if we know the Jordan form of $\varphi$, can we get the decomposition as ($*$) directly?

Comment: I guess you really mean $f\cdot v=f(\varphi)(v)$, that is, first compute the polynomial $f$ on $\varphi$, and then apply the result to the vector $v$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The characteristic polynomial will be the product of the $g_{i}$.

The minimal polynomial is slightly more complicated. First note that the decomposition (*) is not unique. But it becomes unique if you insist on the $g_{i}$ being monic, and require the divisibility conditions 
$$
g_{1} \mid g_{2} \mid \dots \mid g_{r}.
$$
Then $g_{r}$ is your minimal polynomial.

Coming to Jordan, you can also write (*) (recall, it is not unique) so that each $g_{i}$ is of the form $g_{i}(x) = (x -\lambda_{i})^{e_{i}}$. Then each such $g_{i}$ corresponds to a Jordan block of size $e_{i}$, with eigenvalue $\lambda_{i}$. This should also answer your last question.

Comment: Thanks!........